# How can Paypal store credit card numbers and ccv?

Tags: database, security, paypal, credit-card

How can paypal store credit card numbers and CCV without worrying that the database can be compromised ?

Comment: To be pedantic… They don't store CCV because no one can (legally) store CCV. Also, apart from “carefully”, it's not clear what kind of answer you're looking for here; what aspect are you interested in? Finally, they don't worry about it because they probably have lots and lots of insurance.

Comment: and your programming questions is.....

Comment: when I pay with paypal ( without having cash on it ) then paypal get money from the associated credit card without asking me CCV or credit card number. So paypal do store CCV... or not ?

Comment: Why do you care what PayPal specifically does? Do you want to know how to do something simliar in your own porgram or are you trying to hack PayPal to steal their credit card numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot store the CCV number.  Paypal uses this number to verify the credit card. Then they store the rest of the information encrypted,  and the record is marked as "verified".

Comment: when I pay with paypal ( without having cash on it ) then paypal get money from the associated credit card without asking me CCV or credit card number. So paypal do store CCV... or not ?

Comment: @xRobot it is against PCI-DSS to store the CCV number.  Paypal does not store this number nor do they need it after the initial verification.